# Align string in a column in a java

Tags: java, string, alignment

I ahve been trying to align my strings in a column but can't find a solution.
This is what I'm getting - [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0Yzf.png)

You can see how the strings are not aligned. Can someone help me to align them. This is what I'm using.

```
String padded = String.format("%-12s       %-12s       %-12s       %-12s       %-12s", currentBalancepadded, radioButtonSelectedPadded, transactionAmountPadded, newBalancePadded, "X");
```

Comment: Are you using a fixed width font as well?

Comment: Why not put them in a table?

Answer (score 0):

You are using left-justification for all the strings. Try using right-justification for the strings representing amounts. This will align the decimal places properly.

```
String padded = String.format("%12s %-12s %12s %12s %-12s", currentBalancepadded, radioButtonSelectedPadded, transactionAmountPadded, newBalancePadded, "X");
```

You may need to adjust the "12" to get the exact alignment with your headings.

Answer (score 0):

You should try concatenating your strings. To add a new line you should  concatenate the **/n** character before the string that you want to be on a new line.

For example:

```
public class Test 
{
public static void main (String[]  args)
   {
    String String1 = "";
    String String2 = "";
    String String3 = "";
    System.out.print(String1 + "/n" + String2 + "/n" + String3);
   }
}
```

Comment: This does nothing for the indentation which is the problem.